# Getting a max/min date value from an associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5

Below, (tickets :have_many => logs), I'm just listing the 'created_at' value of index 0.   What I'd like to get is the max & min values for that field (saying something like 'first log was 07-01-2011, last log entry 07-18-2011')

```
<% @tickets.each do |t| %>    
    <% if  !t.log_entries[0].nil? %>
       <%= t.log_entries[0].created_at %>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Is there an easy way to do this?   I tried playing around with Max but couldn't figure out a working syntax.   The only other thing I can thing of is to do a find_first asc & desc query in the view.

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily do this by a **Rails subquery**:

```
 From <%= @ticket.log_entries.find(:first, :order => "created_at ASC").created_at.to_s %>
 to <%= @ticket.log_entries.find(:first, :order => "created_at DESC").created_at.to_s %>
```

Happy coding :)